# Call function with no argument and no default argument defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, passport.js

From the example [here](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-facebook/blob/master/examples/login/app.js#LC75):

```js
app.get('/account', ensureAuthenticated, function(req, res){
    res.render('account', { user: req.user });
});

function ensureAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) { return next(); }
    res.redirect('/login')
}
```

I don't understand how `ensureAuthenticated` works. It requires 3 arguments, no default argument is set. But if I call it with no argument (in `app.get`), it does execute correctly, how could this be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not actually calling `ensureAuthenticated` anywhere in your code; you're **passing a reference** to the function, and your http framework calls the function *later* (when a request is made to `/account`) passing the correct arguments.

If you had written `ensureAuthenticated()` (with parentheses), then you'd be calling it with no parameters. Without parentheses, you're passing a reference to the function.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript parameter values are always optional.

Any named arguments that have not been passed are simply `undefined`.

Comment: in `ensureAuthenticated`, `res.redirect` is called correctly, which means `res` is **defined** ???

Comment: @PellaeonLin: That's called by Express, which does pass three arguments.